# How to make a 5-Year calculation by matching date variables in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, date, pandas-groupby, date-arithmetic

The objective is to determine the price percent change within a group (ticker). The percent change must be between 5 years of the date variable. The table below indicates the table I have now:

[image]

The final output would look like the following:

[image]

Some ideas I have experimented with include calculating the 5-year date for each record then iterate through the data frame, pairing the matching records. Then saving the records into a tuple. I think this approach would be very inefficient though. Any ideas?

Any ideas or help is greatly appreciated!